# finding the first non-zero element in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

There is an array of length N in shared memory. The array is sparse (there are lots of zero elements).

```
__shared__ int arr[N];
```

The goal is that all threads in the block (say 128 threads) should find the first index j where N > j >= a and arr[j] is non-zero. The obvious way to do it is:

```
for(int i = a; i < N; i++){
  if(!arr[i]){
    j = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

However, this method is not parallel (threads do not cooperate) and also there is severe bank conflict. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) problem. You are basically finding the minimum, with an appropriate predicate test.  I'll write some code to demonstrate.  To keep things simple I'll make some simplifying assumptions, such as we want to do a simple shared memory reduction (vs. e.g. warp-shuffle):

```
const int nTPB = 128;
// assume nTPB, number of threads per block, is a power of 2
...
__shared__ int arr[N];
__shared__ int red[nTPB];
// code which populates arr ...
// ...
red[threadIdx.x] =  N;
__syncthreads();
// perform test
for (int ridx = threadIdx.x+a; ridx < N; ridx += nTPB){ // block-stride loop
  int t1 = arr[ridx]?ridx:N;
  red[threadIdx.x] = min(t1, red[threadIdx.x]);}
__syncthreads();
// standard min-finding sweep reduction in shared memory
for (int ridx = nTPB>>1; ridx > 0; ridx>>=1){
  if (threadIdx.x < ridx) red[threadIdx.x] = min(red[threadIdx.x], red[threadIdx.x+ridx]);
  __syncthreads();}
// result is now in red[0]
// a result value of N indicates that all values in range [a, N) were 0
```

Here is a quick test case:

```
$ cat t1640.cu
#include <iostream>

const int nTPB = 128;
const int N = 1045;
const int a = 23;
// assume nTPB, number of threads per block, is a power of 2
__global__ void k(int *d, int *r){
  __shared__ int arr[N];
  __shared__ int red[nTPB];
// code which populates arr ...
  for (int ridx = threadIdx.x; ridx < N; ridx += nTPB) // block-stride loop
    arr[ridx] = d[ridx];
  red[threadIdx.x] =  N;
  __syncthreads();
// perform test
  for (int ridx = threadIdx.x+a; ridx < N; ridx += nTPB){ // block-stride loop
    int t1 = arr[ridx]?ridx:N;
    red[threadIdx.x] = min(t1, red[threadIdx.x]);}
  __syncthreads();
// standard min-finding sweep reduction in shared memory
  for (int ridx = nTPB>>1; ridx > 0; ridx>>=1){
    if (threadIdx.x < ridx) red[threadIdx.x] = min(red[threadIdx.x], red[threadIdx.x+ridx]);
    __syncthreads();}
// result is now in red[0]
// a result value of N indicates that all values in range [a, N) were 0
  if (!threadIdx.x) *r = red[0];
}

int main(){

  int *h_d, *d_d, *h_r, *d_r;
  h_d = new int[N];
  h_r = new int[1];
  cudaMalloc(&d_d, N*sizeof(d_d[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_r, sizeof(d_r[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) h_d[i] = 0;
  h_d[44] = 1;
  cudaMemcpy(d_d, h_d, N*sizeof(d_d[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  k<<<1, nTPB>>>(d_d, d_r);
  cudaMemcpy(h_r, d_r, sizeof(d_r[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  std::cout << h_r[0] << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1640 t1640.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1640
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
44
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how there is a bank conflict here, you are doing all the job in one thread. My solution would be to stride by the block size and set a flag if the index is found.

```
__shared__ int arr[N];
__shared__ bool index_found = false;
__shared__ int current_found[128];  //assuming block size is 128. Assuming this is initialized to all falses.
int block_size = blockDim.x;
int thread_id = threadIdx.x;
for(int i = thread_id; (i < N) && !index_found ; i += block_size){ //stride by block_size
    if(arr[i] && (i >= a)){
        current_found[thread_id] = i;  // this only marks, at which iteration the value is found. But doesn't guarantee that there is a single index found. We need to find the absolute solution among possible indices.
        index_found = true;
    }
    __syncthreads();  // make sure all threads wait for shared writes
}
if(thread_id ==0){  // in master thread, find the index among possible values
    //mandatory sequential part
    for(int i = 0; i < 128 ; i++){
        if(current_found[i]){
            // i is your index. Get your index here the way you want.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code is not tested and written in the web editor.

Comment: our answers are similar.  The main difference is that thing you are calling "mandatory sequential part" need not be done in a sequential fashion as you are indicating.  You can use all threads collectively there in a typical shared memory parallel reduction, to find the (lowest) index.  Your code also has a bug for the case where `a` is 0 and the actual first non-zero value occurs at index `i=0`

Comment: Yes, the sequential part can also be parallelized by reduction. I don't understand why there is a bug. I am marking the `current_found` when `i>=a`.

Comment: what if `i` is zero (when a non-zero value is found)? Then `current_found[thread_id]` holds zero, and `if(current_found[i])` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Thank you :)

Comment: Since my reputation is not enough to post a comment, I want to note something about your code. In the block stride loop, you are looping unnecessarily more, you can stop once a value is found. Because, we want the first non-zero element, not the minimum or maximum.

Comment: Yes, your first loop can also be optimized by starting at `i=thread_id+a` instead of `i=thread_id`.  In the case of early-exit that you are proposing, this optimizes the average execution time but makes the worst-case execution time even longer.